# MySQL STR_TO_DATE doesn't work in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, temp-tables

I am trying to check in MySQL if I can convert the column type from varchar to date. If not, the DB_IDs should be stored in a temporary table. When I execute the query, everything works fine. However, as soon as I combine it with creating the temporary table, the subquery fails with an error.

```sql
-- doesn't work
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS my_temp_id_table;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_id_table(
SELECT DB_ID from verkehrsweg v where DB_ID in (
    SELECT DB_ID 
    FROM verkehrsweg v1 
    where STR_TO_DATE(v1.LASTUPDATEDBY, GET_FORMAT(DATE,'ISO')) is null) 
and LASTUPDATEDBY is not null );

-- works fine
SELECT DB_ID 
from verkehrsweg v 
where DB_ID in (
    SELECT DB_ID 
    FROM verkehrsweg v1 
    where STR_TO_DATE(v1.LASTUPDATEDBY, GET_FORMAT(DATE,'ISO')) is null) 
and LASTUPDATEDBY is not null ;
```

Error Message:

Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: 'Hallo' for function str_to_date

From documentation:
STR_TO_DATE(str,format)

This is the inverse of the DATE_FORMAT() function. It takes a string str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts. If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning.

EDIT:
My table has the following structure.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>DB_ID (BIGINT)</th>
    <th>DATECREATED (DATETIME)</th>
    <th>DATEUPDATED (DATETIME)</th>
    <th>LASTUPDATEDBY (VARCHAR 255)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>2022-12-15</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>hallo</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `'Hallo'` is not date value really. Check do you use correct column name as an argument.

Comment: I know. The query should return the DB_ID of any row that does not have a date value in the specified column.

Comment: I added some sample data.

Comment: Post the result of `select @@SESSION.sql_mode`

Comment: The column name `LASTUPDATEDBY` suggests to be not a date but an author? Please check and explain.

Comment: select @@SESSION.sql_mode returned 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

Comment: The name of the column is a little misleading, but it is just sample data. I am currently working on a query that checks if a column can be converted to a date for the purpose of data cleansing.